# Angular Promise not logging uncaught exception

Tags: angular, exception, promise, angular5

I am currently using Angular 5.2.4. I've recently realised that exceptions/errors thrown inside a promise disappeared when they are not catched.

I remembered that this used to be the normal behavior of Promise on previous version of angular, but now it should display something like:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: exception message, etc.

Now, if I use this code (as component):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "o-test-component",
  template: "<button (click)='test()'>test button</button>",
  styles: [""]
})
export class TestComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  test() {
    console.log("testing ...");
    const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject("rejecting a");
    });
    a.then(() => console.log("test"));
    console.log("test2");
    const m = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      throw new Error("throwing b");
    });
    console.log("end test");
  }
}
```

I get:

> testing ...
>
> test2
>
> end test

No such "uncaught exception" is ever logged when I click the button.

If I copy the `test()` method content directly in chrome console, I get these:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: throwing b ; Zone: <root> ; Task: null ; Value: Error: throwing b
at Promise (<anonymous>:8:13)
at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:875)
at <anonymous>:7:15 Error: throwing b
at Promise (<anonymous>:8:13)
at new ZoneAwarePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:875:29)
at <anonymous>:7:15
```

And

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: rejecting a ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: rejecting a undefined
```

Any idea on why there are no logs in component? Is this normal ? Or maybe there is something  in my project that prevents logging of uncaught exception thrown in promise ?

I've heard that the bluebird library can solve this problem, but that now it shouldn't be used for this as logging should be default behavior (now that Promise is native)

Comment: Angular should log the uncaught exceptions. See sthe stack blitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kf8qdq 

Do you have a custom ErrorHandler in the project? You can find this by searching for references of `ErrorHandler`

Comment: @nipuna777 Yes, this is the behaviour I was expecting. Unfortunately, no ErrorHandler in my project.

Comment: Did you check for packages that could be causing this?

Comment: You're using a bad promise polyfill probably, can you `console.log(Promise)` and tell us what it logs?

Comment: "I've heard that the bluebird library can solve this problem, but that now it shouldn't be used for this as logging should be default behavior (now that Promise is native)" - as a bluebird maintainer and one of the persons involved I can confirm that is the case.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Indeed, Promise are "ZoneAwarePromise" definied in zone.js (in polyfills bundle.js).

Comment: @nipuna777 There is quite a few package in this project I'm gonna take look. So far I've found "loud-rejection" which is supposed to do what I want (but I don't see it used)

Comment: @Asoub do you have a zone error handler?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it doesn't seem so, although I am not sure what is should look like. I've searhced "handler", "onerror", "zone". Isn't zone the default "Promise manager" in angular ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

Well, for some reason, the file where errors were logged (`core.js`) was filtered by the browsers. I saw it later, but there was a little "23 hidden" in the right corner. The left pane also displays all files where logs are created.

To solve this: in Chrome console, right click -> filter -> uncheck files that are filtered.

**Other clues**

If you're stuck on the problem and this is not your solution, you can read the comments of the question and check these:

-Check with multiple browsers.

-Check if you're using pollyfills for Promise. Default class for angular 5 are "ZoneAwarePromise"; use console.log(Promise) to display your.

-Check if they're displays when you use this stackblitz: stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kf8qdq

-Check if you don't have a custom error handler: something that catches "PromiseRejectionEvent"

-If you're using `ZoneAwarePromise` you can add debug breakpoints in `zone.js` and check in `resolvePromise()` where `REJECTED_NO_CATCH` code is being used if the error is adde in `_uncaughtPromiseErrors` array.

-Also check that `api.showUncaughtError()` returns true (even though the `api.onUnhandledError()` doesn't seem to be called)